# How can I generate multiple plots from reading a file in the same window using matplotlib - Pyhton

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two .txt files and with them, I would like to plot the graphs corresponding to each file in the same window. I managed to plot only one. Using the code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timecap = []
qtd = []

# f = open('dataset.txt', 'r')

for line in open('pkts_by_src.txt', 'r'):
    lines = [i for i in line.split(',')]
    timecap.append(lines[0])
    qtd.append(int(lines[1]))

plt.title("Capture")
plt.xlabel('time cap')
plt.ylabel('qtd')
plt.yticks(qtd)
plt.plot(timecap, qtd, marker='o', c='g')

plt.show()
```

The file is in this format:

```
22:40:16,2
22:40:20,1
22:40:20,2
22:40:23,1
22:40:23,4
22:40:23,6
22:40:23,8
```

Can you give me a tip? I'm a beginner in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the subplot function as shown. After calling it make your graph the repeat, at the end do show(), you can look at the matplotlib documentation for specific parameters.

```
plt.subplot(211)
for line in open('pkts_by_src.txt', 'r'):
    lines = [i for i in line.split(',')]
   ...

plt.subplot(212)
for line in open('wordlist2.txt', 'r'):
    lines = [i for i in line.split(',')]
   ...

plt.show()
```